# How many turns does it take for an unseen servant to pass a healing potion in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, action-economy

The spell *unseen servant* reads:

> Once on each of your turns as a bonus action, you can mentally command
> the servant to move up to 15 feet and interact with an object. The
> servant can perform simple tasks that a human servant could do, such
> as fetching things, cleaning, mending, folding clothes, lighting
> fires, serving food, and pouring wine. Once you give the command, the
> servant performs the task to the best of its ability until it
> completes the task, then waits for your next command.

Assume I used my bonus action to command it to give the healing potion in my pocket to another character, and that they are within reach (15 feet) when I do.

It would take a player one turn to complete the task: A free item interaction to draw the potion, then movement, followed by an action to safely pass it over. But the unseen servant seems to be solely capable of movement *then* a single item interaction.

**How many turns would it take for it to perform this task? And if two or more are necessary what is the order of operations? Can it move after interacting with an object?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the last question first. Can it move after interacting with an object?

The following reference to [actions on Your Turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn) lists the actions that a character can utilize:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and take one action.

The text then goes on to explain that you can choose the order in which you perform these actions. This additional text demonstrates that even though movement is listed before action, it does not offer any ordering keywords such as you move and "then" take one action. Thus, the sentence itself does not provide any ordering keywords.

Similarly, the text for Unseen Servant does not offer any ordering keywords that would imply movement must precede item interaction. Since an order is not directly stated, it seems justified that because this word pattern matches that of a character's actions on "your turn", the unseen servant's potential actions (movement and item interaction) can occur in either order, as well.

Now, for the main question you are asking: how many turns would be required?

The action of giving an object to someone else is actually a compound action. They are also taking the object. Is seems clear that the unseen servant does not have the ability to give the object as part of the same action that it grabbed the object and moved. But, the rules are less clear on what happens if the character attempts to take the object from the unseen servant on the other character's turn. Can the Unseen Servant release its grasp of the object off-turn? Or would the player have to wrestle the potion away?

I do not think the ability to release an object requires an "item interaction" action. If this is the case, then it seems that it could take less than two turns for the unseen servant to complete its task, provided the other character assists with a free action item interaction on their turn to take the potion. If the other character does not assist, then it would take two turns to complete.

Answer (score 1):

"Object interaction" is a bit of a loose term (it would be hard for rules to cater for every situation). You've already said, taking an item from an easily accessible place - like a pocket - can be done with a free object interaction, but don't forget that the other player also gets a free object interaction.

In my view you could use your bonus action for the servant to take the potion (free interaction) and move 15'. That would be it for the servant. Now on the other player's turn they could move if necessary and take the potion from the servant as their free object interaction, then use their action to drink it.

So it would take your turn for the servant to grab the potion and move, then the other player's turn to take the potion and drink. All within one round.